# How to use versioning in laravel mix outside of a laravel project

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, laravel-mix

When creating a project that is outside of Laravel, there is no way to use versioning, because there is no mix directive. The only way is to create a Mix.php class and implement the directive's functionality.

So, instead of index.html, I've created index.php and required the Mix class. Everything works fine. The problem now is the webpack dev server doesn't parse php files and I won't be able to have hot reload. If I access it with http://localhost:8080/index.php the server downloads the file, which is a normal behavior, since it doesn't care about php.

Anyone had this problem before? Please share your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There is no need to call localhost:8080 directly. The only thing that I have to do is to open my virtual host and point all my assets to localhost:8080. Hot reload works!

As for the versioning, I use versioning only on production, where hot reload does not exist and the problem mentioned above is not valid!